# Multiple IDs list in tapply

Tags: r, mean, tapply

I want to calculate the mean of a variable in different groups. To define the groups I want to utilise the combination of two column in the data frame that describe the single observations:

```
a<-sample(12)
b<-sample(-100:100, 12)
d<-c(-11:0)
O<-rep(c("Nn","Hy"), each=6)
H<-rep(c("In+", "In-"), each=3, times=2) 
ID<-rep(c("bo","co", "do", "fo"), each=3)
mydata<-data.frame(ID, a, b, d, O, H)
gg.df <- melt(mydata, id.var=c("ID", "O", "H"), variable.name="int")

mean.w<-tapply(subset( x= gg.df, subset = int == "a") , 
list(gg.df$O, gg.df$H), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in tapply(subset(x = gg.df, subset = int == "a"), list(gg.df$O,  : 
  arguments must have same length
```

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `aggregate(value ~ O + H, subset(gg.df, int == "a"), mean)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think perhaps you are looking for either one of these solutions.  With `tapply()` the first argument is a vector, not the entire data set.  From `help(tapply)`

> **Usage**
>
> `tapply(X, INDEX, FUN = NULL, ..., simplify = TRUE)`
>
> **Arguments**
>
> `X`
> an atomic object, typically a vector.

I have found that `tapply()` is easier to understand if we begin the call with `with()`.  Here we can use the subset in the call to `with()` then the `tapply()` call is much easier to read.

```
with(subset(gg.df, int == "a"), tapply(value, list(O, H), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
#         In-      In+
# Hy 5.000000 8.000000
# Nn 5.333333 7.666667

aggregate(value ~ O + H, subset(gg.df, int == "a"), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#    O   H    value
# 1 Hy In- 5.000000
# 2 Nn In- 5.333333
# 3 Hy In+ 8.000000
# 4 Nn In+ 7.666667
```

Note that you could also use `gg.df[gg.df$int == "a", ]` for the subset in place of using `subset()`.  Also note that we can get a bit more informative result is we use `data.frame()` in `tapply()` instead of `list()`

```
with(subset(gg.df, int == "a"), tapply(value, data.frame(O, H), mean))
#     H
# O         In-      In+
#   Hy 5.000000 8.000000
#   Nn 5.333333 7.666667
```

Comment: Is it possible to get "a" inside the tapply? I tried `gg.df[int=="a",]` but this approach works only for `id.var`

Comment: Well I suppose you could do `tapply(gg.df[gg.df$int == "a", "value"], gg.df[gg.df$int == "a", c("O", "H")], mean)` but then you would be subsetting for `a` twice which may be less efficient.  This also is a good illustration of why we use `with()` there

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydata %>% 
  gather(int, value, -O, -H, -ID) %>%
  filter(int == "a") %>%
  group_by(O, H) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Which gives:

```
#       O      H    value
#  (fctr) (fctr)    (dbl)
#1     Hy    In- 7.333333
#2     Hy    In+ 6.666667
#3     Nn    In- 6.666667
#4     Nn    In+ 5.333333
```